# Foundation clearing-lightbox thumbnails not working

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, thumbnails

I am trying to use the clearing lightbox in foundation and the the -th class doesn't convert my image to a thumbnail, it just shows a broken image icon.

The link is http://halstan.businesscatalyst.com/portfolio-1/Tora

and the specific markup is

```
<ul class="clearing-thumbs" data-clearing>
<li><a class="th" href="/_assets/img/Tora/fourth.jpg"><img alt="" src="/_assets/img/Tora/fourth-th.jpg" /></a></li>
<li><a class="th" href="/_assets/img/Tora/third.jpg"><img alt="" src="/_assets/img/Tora/third-th.jpg" /></a></li>
<li><a class="th" href="/_assets/img/Tora/ToraSlider.png"><img alt="" src="/_assets/img/Tora/ToraSlider-th.png" /></a></li>
</ul>
```